# Setting Add-Role to true for Vagrant Azure Plugin

Tags: azure, vagrant

I am using Vagrant to try and make boxes on the Azure cloud.
I am using the Azure plug-in

I can make cloud Service "cloudservice1"
and put a VM "box1" in it

I can make cloud Service "cloudservice2"
and put a VM "box2" in it

when I run vagrant up on two different Vagrantfiles
it looks like:
cloudservice1 contains box1
cloudservice2 contains box2

But if I try to make both Vagrantfiles deploy to the same cloud service:
The goal is to make it so that "cloudservice1" contains both "box1" and "box2"

I get the issue that:
"The specified deployment slot Production is occupied"

I can see that 
"default: Add Role? - false"

Is in the output when running vagrant up, and I believe the issue is that I need to set that to True to be able to add another box to an existing cloudservice.

I've searched for a while and can't seem to find anything with Azure+Vagrant.
at a DevOp, I was told I may need to open the Plug=in gem and change where that line is myself.

Is there an alternative to this or a better workaround?

Thanks
EDIT:
I've tried a single file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = 'azure'

    config.vm.provision "fix-no-tty", type: "shell" do |s|
        s.privileged = false
        s.inline = "sudo sed -i '/tty/!s/mesg n/tty -s \\&\\& mesg n/' /root/.profile"
    end

    do_common_azure_stuff = Proc.new do |azure, override|
        azure.mgmt_certificate = "CERT LOCATION"
        azure.mgmt_endpoint = 'https://management.core.windows.net'
        azure.subscription_id = 'ID'
        azure.storage_acct_name = 'dev1' # optional. A new one will be generated if not provided.

        azure.vm_image = 'b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-14_04-LTS-amd64-server-20140528-en-us-30GB'
        azure.vm_user = 'USER' # defaults to 'vagrant' if not provided
        azure.vm_password = 'PASSWORD'# min 8 characters. should contain a lower case letter, an uppercase letter, a number and a special character

        azure.vm_name = "DEV"
        azure.cloud_service_name = "DEV-test" # same as vm_name. leave blank to auto-generate
        azure.deployment_name = "DevDeployment" # defaults to cloud_service_name
        azure.vm_location = 'East US' # e.g., West US, Este de EE. UU.
    end

    config.ssh.username = 'USER' # modify this username
    config.ssh.password = 'PASSWORD' # If windows or user/pass auth enabled

    config.vm.define 'app1' do |cfg|
        cfg.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
          do_common_azure_stuff.call azure, override
          azure.vm_name = 'app1-DEV'
        end
      end

    config.vm.define 'app2' do |cfg|
        cfg.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
          do_common_azure_stuff.call azure, override
          azure.vm_name = 'app2-DEV'
        end
      end

    config.vm.define 'app3' do |cfg|
        cfg.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
          do_common_azure_stuff.call azure, override
          azure.vm_name = 'app3-DEV'
        end
      end
end
```

In this case all the boxes end up with
 [31m[1mConflictError : The specified deployment slot Production is occupied.[0m[0m

and two files - changing App Name for the file, and running in to different folders:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

APP_NAME = "app1"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

config.vm.box = 'azure'
config.vm.provision "fix-no-tty", type: "shell" do |s|
    s.privileged = false
    s.inline = "sudo sed -i '/tty/!s/mesg n/tty -s \\&\\& mesg n/' /root/.profile"
end

config.vm.provider :azure do |azure|
    azure.mgmt_certificate = "CERT"
    azure.mgmt_endpoint = 'https://management.core.windows.net'
    azure.subscription_id = 'ID'
    azure.storage_acct_name = 'dev1' # optional. A new one will be generated if not provided.

    azure.vm_image = 'b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-14_04-LTS-amd64-server-20140528-en-us-30GB'
    azure.vm_user = 'USER' # defaults to 'vagrant' if not provided
    azure.vm_password = 'PASSWORD' # min 8 characters. should contain a lower case letter, an uppercase letter, a number and a special character

    azure.vm_name = "#{APP_NAME}-DEV"
    azure.cloud_service_name = "DEV-CLOUD" # same as vm_name. leave blank to auto-generate
    azure.deployment_name = "DevDeployment" # defaults to cloud_service_name
    azure.vm_location = 'East US' # e.g., West US, Este de EE. UU.


end
config.ssh.username = 'USER' # modify this username
config.ssh.password = 'PASSWORD' # If windows or user/pass auth enabled

end
```

In this case the second box ran ends up with
[31m[1mConflictError : The specified deployment slot Production is occupied.[0m[0m

Comment: whats your Vagrantfile ? are you looking for [this set up](https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure#multi-machine)

Comment: I've done that set up, but you still get the same issue.

I've also tried doing two different VagrantFiles

Comment: I was bitten by this today. Issue already filed for that - https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure/issues/97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in plugin versions <= 1.2.1. An [issue](https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure/issues/97) is already filed on Github as well as a [pull request](https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure/pull/98).

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-azure
Installing the 'vagrant-azure' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-azure (1.2.1)'!
```

Comment: According to another issue the feature was working in earlier versions of vagrant-azure and this behaviour needs to be fixed in version 1.2.1. I may review my answer in time. https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure/issues/76